# unbind touchmove event in jquery

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I invoke the following to prevent scrolling on a web app:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

But on one page I need to cancel this. What would the opposite of this be? So when the page is called, I can call something like:

`$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault() == TRUE});` or something

Comment: ...as opposed to just leaving out the code altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').unbind('touchmove');
```

`unbind` **[docs:](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)**

> Description: Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

Comment: Wonderful! WORKS PEFECTLY! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The opposite would be `$('body').unbind('touchmove');`.

Comment: Cheers! Does the job pefectly :)