# Issue with mobile navigation I'm trying to fix (JS or CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scroll, nav

I'm currently encountering issues with a mobile navigation I have created. It's a simple hamburger icon and when you click it, it opens a fullscreen menu. The problem is I'm trying to disable scrolling when the overlay is visible. Now I figured I could achieve this by adding;

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

But this doesn't toggle within the click event.
How would I achieve it, so that it toggles? When clicked again scrolling should be possible again. The full script;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".icon").click(function () {
    $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

very useful link :

[How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery)
This code works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $('html, body').css({
         overflow: 'hidden',
         height: '100%'
      });
      $("p").toggleClass("main");
   });
   $('html, body').css({
   overflow: 'auto',
   height: 'auto'});  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I cant seem to fit this in with the current script I have for the interactive hamburger icon. Can I not toggle a class, which adds those specific css rules to the body/html?

Comment: I have been fiddling around with the css way and got it to work, but it is still able to scroll a little bit because of iOS. The URL bar is able to get a bit smaller when the user tries to scroll. I think it can only be achieved by js unfortunately.

Comment: Can you provide the css and the html file ?Are you using <script> tag for js in the html file?

Comment: I can give you the url of the website. It's currently live and I work with less instead of css. http://www.epicconcepts.nl

Comment: This works as it should;
    $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
except when you click again, you should be able to scroll again. That rule simply needs to be bind and unbind, by the same click.

Comment: I know what you mean now.Yes your right ,you should probably use the unbind then :.$('#some_link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
$('#some_link').unbind('click'); See if this helps .

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm looking for, but I am not that experienced with js, so I couldn't figure out how to implement that in the script I had, because I only have a single click event. I'm not sure how to add the unbind part.

Comment: You can look into this too: too.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551389/how-to-unbind-a-listener-that-is-calling-event-preventdefault-using-jquery . I cannot test my code on the device. Is there a way you can provide your js as code here?  Can you add  $('body').unbind(''touchmove"); outside the click function and try ?

Comment: The code as I have it right now is listed above in original question. Somewhere in that script I need to add the unbind function, but I'm not sure where and how.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".icon").click(function () {
    $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault();});
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  }); 
  $('body').unbind('touchmove'); 
});
```

Can you try this?

Comment: I changed it.Typo

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think it doesn't unbind it or return it to false.

Comment: There is a semicolon after e.preventDefault, I hope you have corrected that when adding the script?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Aha behind (), yeah I removed it.

Comment: function(e){e.preventDefault()}); to this function(e){e.preventDefault();}); the first one doesnt end with semi colon in your first post. Even this link has the same way on unbinding .You should add semi colon.:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194843/unbind-touchmove-event-in-jquery

Comment: Aha, so I should add the ; between () and }?

Comment: I have added the semicolon, but nothing has changed.